# Send values from Servlet to JSP without cookies andr session not being shown on URL

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, cookies

I'm new to servlet and JSP, so I'll be brief.

I want to send some values from servlet to JSP, but my reviewers advise not to use cookies. I tried using session, but the redirected URL keeps showing values embedded in them.

Illustration

http://local host:8088/webkl/index.jsp?name=a1&age=a2

I don't wish to show name and age in the URL, how do I do it?

Not sure what's wrong. Please help?

Comment: From servlet to jsp.  Don't you mean jsp to servlet?

Comment: No Robert Moskal, its from servlet to JSP, we have a third party tool which we need to customize, thus a request from the main tool is redirected to a servlet and then from servlet to the JSP in consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use POST method and you can refer bellow sample code :

login.jsp

```
<form action="loginOperation" method="post" onsubmit="return LoginValidate()" name="login">
   <input class="textbox" name="useremail" type="text" placeholder="useremail"> 
   <input class="textbox" name="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>
```

login.java(servlet):-

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {  
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
    throws ServletException, IOException {  

response.setContentType("text/html");  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

String n=request.getParameter("useremail");  
String p=request.getParameter("password");  

if(LoginDao.validate(n, p)){  
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2");  
    rd.forward(request,response);  
}  
else{  
    out.print("Sorry username or password error");  
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");  
    rd.include(request,response);  
}  

out.close();  
}  
}
```

web.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Demo</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>

 </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.demo.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/loginOperation</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

The GET method is the default method to send information to web server. Since the GET method appends plain text string to the URL. We should avoid using GET method to send password or other sensitive information to the server.
The GET method also has size limitation. We can send only 1024 characters in a request string. This information sent is accessible getQueryString() and getParameter() methods of request object.
POST method is more reliable method of sending information to the server. This method sends the information as a separate message.
JSP handles this type of requests using getParameter() method to read simple parameters and getInputStream() method to read binary data stream coming from the client.

JSP handles form data using the following methods.

```
<form action="main.jsp" method="GET/POST">
     First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">
     Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1-Use "post" method instead of "get".
It will not show values while passing,There will be nothing shown in the url.

example:-

`<form action="page_name.php" method="post">`
`First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>`
``` name: <input type="text" n``ame="lname"><br> ```
`input type="submit" value="Submit">`
`</form>`

2-After submitting u can retrieve the values of firstname and lastname without passing them through the (url).